# if else condition is not working in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I'm trying to use the if-else condition in my scripted Jenkinsfile to run the builds depending on the choice parameters that are being passed at the beginning of the pipeline. On passing `pt` as choice for ENVIRONMENT parameter it is still not executing the else block.

```
 stage("Docker Build") {
        echo "1. Environment is ${ENVIRONMENT}"
      if (env.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev'||'uat') {
          echo "2. Environment is ${ENVIRONMENT}"
          echo "This is Dev stage"

        docker.image("nexus-az.${dockerBuildImageVersion}").inside("-e HOME=${WORKSPACE}") {
          sh 'npm run run-envsub -- --env CONTEXTPATH=/app-${ENVIRONMENT}'
          sh 'ng build --configuration=${ENVIRONMENT}-oci --base-href /app-${ENVIRONMENT}/'
        }

      } else {
          echo "3. Environment is ${ENVIRONMENT}"
          echo "This is PT stage"
          docker.image("nexus-az.${dockerBuildImageVersion}").inside("-e HOME=${WORKSPACE}") {
            sh 'npm run run-envsub -- --env CONTEXTPATH=/app-${ENVIRONMENT}'
            sh 'ng build --configuration=w${ENVIRONMENT}-oci --base-href /app-${ENVIRONMENT}/'
        }
}
```

And gives the following output

```
[Pipeline] { (Docker Build)
[Pipeline] echo
1. Environment is pt
[Pipeline] echo
2. Environment is pt
[Pipeline] echo
This is Dev stage
[Pipeline] isUnix
.
.
.
+ ng build --configuration=pt-oci --base-href /app-oci-pt/
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'pt-oci' is not set in the workspace.
```

1. I have tried to use `if (params.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev'||'uat')'  but seeing the same behavior.
2. Tried declaring `ENVIRONMENT = "${params.ENVIRONMENT}"` before the stage to define it as a global variable and then use `if (${ENVIRONMENT} == 'dev'||'uat')` but doesn't help either.
3. Added multiple echo statements to see what the value of ENVIRONMENT is which resolves to `pt` but still not executing the else block.

Expected Behavior:
It should enter the else block and print

```
[Pipeline] echo
1. Environment is pt
[Pipeline] echo
3. Environment is pt
[Pipeline] echo
This is PT stage
```

Comment: can you try to echo out ENVIRONMENT In the console see if has the correct value.

Comment: @agent_bean I tried doing that. If you see the output shared it is echoing pt for ENVIRONMENT.

Comment: it means you aren't setting the environment variable prior.

Comment: @agent_bean as mentioned, I've tried doing that also by declaring `ENVIRONMENT = "${params.ENVIRONMENT}"` am I doing something wrong here? I thought the parameter that we configure for the pipeline (the parameters are not being set in the script) are available as environment variables by default.

Comment: in the command line try 
export ENVIRONMENT=value
then
echo $ENVIRONMENT 
what happens?

Comment: I'm running the script in the Jenkins console and even after exporting the ENVIRONMENT value in the stage before the if condition I don't see anything change.

Comment: ENVIRONMENT Should equal to value when you echo it out. I don't know why your environment variable isn't updating.

Comment: @agent_bean that's the issue. The ENVIRONMENT is equaling to the value when I echo it but still not executing the else block. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the condition like below.

```
if(params.ENVIRONMENT.equals("dev") || params.ENVIRONMENT.equals("uat"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Do you have any idea why I'm seeing this behaviour?

Comment: @Samuel AFAIS Your syntax is wrong. You can't have the OR condition like the way you have defined. It should be either `if (env.ENVIRONMENT == 'dev' || env.ENVIRONMENT == 'uat') `  or the way I had it.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.